# SSIS data import in asp.net

Tags: ssis

In my project I have import data from CSV file using SSIS package in asp.net environment. The CSV file contains Header section and details section. The Header section will contains the summary of the details section. The details section contains the records of the item sold by the company. The header will contains the total number of records in the details and sum of the amount of all items. I need to validate the file before importing the data to the database. Please suggest some link or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I tried different ways but only solution of Andy Leonard worked for me.
[SSIS Design Pattern: Loading Variable-Length Rows](https://web.archive.org/web/20190319083635/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2010/05/18/ssis-design-pattern-loading-variable-length-rows.aspx).
I only replaced String.Split by Regex.Split in the Script component.
You can validate the data in Script component.
I installed the Integration Services on the web server but you can choose another option.
[Check this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160307211938/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx)